# Fetch Data From Nested JSON data using curl php

Tags: php, json, curl

So I am fetching data from an URL which is in JSON Format Like this below.

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
  "street": "Kulas Light",
  "suite": "Apt. 556",
  "city": "Gwenborough",
  "zipcode": "92998-3874",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-37.3159",
    "lng": "81.1496"
  }
},
"phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
"website": "hildegard.org",
"company": {
  "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
  "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
  "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
}
},
// And So on upto 10 id places.
```

Now what I want is to Fetch the data in my site using the cURL php .

My php Code looks like this :

```
$url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" ;

$ch = curl_init() ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch) ;

$id = 1;
$data = json_decode($result) ;
foreach ($data as $mydata) {
  if ($mydata["id"] == $id) {
 echo $mydata["address"]["street3"] ;
 break ;
}
}
```

But What I am getting is an error :

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: use $data = json_decode($result,true) ;

Comment: It Gives A new Error `Trying to get property of non-object ` Printed 10 times. @M.Hemant

Comment: The code you have posted works fine with the fix suggested by @M.Hemant https://3v4l.org/oaCPE

Comment: yes because `street3` is not there, look at my answer I just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> second param When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
$data = json_decode($result,true) ;
foreach ($data as $mydata) {
  if ($mydata["id"] == $id) {
      echo $mydata["address"]["street"] ;//changes `street3` is not there
      break ;
  }
}
```

> By default json_decode will return you objects and if you want to use `[]` syntax you need associative array and only for that you need to pass second param `true` please refer this 
>   [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for further queries

Comment: Yes it Works . Thanks. Please can you tell me why this happened ? and please upvote if my question is legit and clear.

Comment: first your typo mistake for `street3` and you don't know the return value type of `json_decode`

Comment: yeah I got that mistakes. Thanks for Explanations. :)